# Why does the alternation operator in Vim work as a command but not as a mapping?

Tags: regex, vim

I want to do a simple mapping of the following command:

```
:'<,'>s/{\|}//gc
```

It will remove all curly brackets in the selected text, asking me before every change. It works perfectly.

If I write this into my .vimrc as a mapping like this:

```
vmap <leader>rc :<C-R>s/{\|}//gc<cr>
```

it suddenly tells me, it cannot match the pattern {|}, thus escaping the | seems not to be working.

Why and how do I create this mapping correctly?

Comment: Why `<C-R>` at the beginning?

Comment: So that it operates on the selected text.

Comment: It eats your `s`. And yes, you need extra escaping: *two backslashes* to get *one backslash* in the mapping.

Comment: @Kampfzwerg_Jana Just leave out `<C-R>` and it will use the area you selected.

Comment: Okay, I deleted the <C-R> and escaped the backslash and pipe so it looks like this now: `vmap <leader>rcb :s/{\\\|}//gc<cr>`
But it is still not working.

Comment: @Kampfzwerg_Jana you need *two* backslashes, not *three*.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just saw your comment. Now its working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following:

```
:vmap <leader>rc :s/{\\|}//gc<CR>
```

It *does* operate on the selected text: for `:` in visual mode, you get `'<,'>` in front of the command.

A useful way to debug this kind of mappings is to leave out the final `<CR>`, so you see the command exactly as it would be executed. That's how I noticed that `<C-R>` ate your `s` (because it expects register name as the next character) and that one layer of escaping is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `<C-R>` after the colon, this currently says, after the colon paste the `s` register then your pattern.

It's unlikely that you have anything in this register so the command line looks like:

```
:/{\|}//gc
```

Which is in fact a range specifier rather than a substitute. We need to only remove that

```
vnoremap <leader>rc :s/{\|}//gc<cr>
```